# auditd misses execution on some commands

Tags: security, monitoring, system-calls, linux-audit

I've placed an auditd rule on the `jcmd` command as follows:

```
auditctl -w /usr/bin/jcmd -p x -k jvm_debug
```

However, when I execute it, it writes nothing to log.

Looking at guides and previous questions on this subject, they use the same format, but give the command `who` as an example.

So I tried it as well:

```
auditctl -w /usr/bin/who -p x -k who
```

For the `who` command, auditd does write a log when executing it.

just for further debugging, I ran those commands with `strace`, telling it to follow `open` and `execve` syscalls.
With open, I'm mostly seeing calls for libraries, but not the executable. However, both commands strace output, starts with an `execve` syscall to the file I ran.

How come auditd "misses" the `execve` system call for the `jcmd` command, but not for the `who` command?